# update inputtext via dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Please help me to find a example to update p:inputtext with data stored in a bean which is set(solved already) by selecting a row of a datatable of a p:dialog.  I have succeeded updating outputtext in the same manner.

I am using (learning) netbeans 7.2 primefaces 3.2, glassfish 3.1

thansk for all your help

rs_ncs

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference components in JSF ajax? Cannot find component with identifier "foo" in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)

Comment: Well it is not a duplicate. My problem is not an identification problem, as I am able to update an outputtext by ID-ing it. My problem is how an inputtext can be updated. Is there any difference?

Comment: Apparently you haven't read the answer on the duplicate. It tells you precisely how to find out the right client ID.

Comment: Thank you BalusC for your effort. But why are you insisting finding the right client ID? I am able to find it if it is an outputtext. My problem is if I change the component to inputtext the update does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/home.jsf) and the [user guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_4.pdf), you'll find everything you need; in detail search for rowSelect event for the datatable component. Good luck =)

Comment: unfortunately there is nothing about the differences updating h:outputtextand p:inputtext

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to update a component on select of a row from a datatable, then you can use the `update` attribute of a `<p:ajax>` which is listening on `rowselect` event. Something like this:

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":xx:xx" />
```

Comment: I am able to update a h:outputtext component from a p:dialog. I need help to update a p:inputtext component from a p:dialog

Answer (score 0):

As Suggested by BalusC the code `<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":xx:xx" />` should work....

Here is an example of updating both inputtext and outputtext .

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable id="usertable" var="user" value="#{userManageBean.userList}"
        rowKey="#{user.U_ID}" selection="#{userManageBean.selectedUser}"
        selectionMode="single" paginator="true" rows="18" >



        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":useredit:edituser" />
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":viewuser:displayuser" />



        <p:column headerText="User Name">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.username}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="FName">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.firstname}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="LName">
            <h:outputText value="#{user.lastname}" />
        </p:column>



    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

<p:dialog id="userview" header="View User" widgetVar="dlg2" >

    <h:form id="viewuser">
        <h:panelGrid id="displayuser" columns="2" cellpadding="4">
            <h:outputText value="User Name:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{userManageBean.selectedUser.username}" />

            <h:outputText value="First Name" />
            <h:outputText value="#{userManageBean.selectedUser.firstname}" />

            <h:outputText value="Last Name:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{userManageBean.selectedUser.lastname}" />

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

</p:dialog>

<p:dialog id="user_edit" header="Edit User" widgetVar="dlgedit" >

    <h:form id="useredit">

        <h:panelGrid id="edituser" columns="2" cellpadding="4">

            <h:outputText value="First Name" />
            <h:inputText value="#{userManageBean.selectedUser.firstname}" />


            <h:outputText value="Last Name" />
            <h:inputText value="#{userManageBean.selectedUser.lastname}" />


            <p:commandButton id="updateUser" value="Add" action="#{someaction}"
                ajax="false" />


        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```